# linear equivalence of divisors given by sections of a linebundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

The topic of divisors is new to me and I wonder if I understand a few things correctly. 
In my situation I have an analytical Manifold $M$ of dimension $2$ and its compactification $\overline M$. I also have a Linebundle $\mathcal L$ on $\overline M$. My question is, if any of the following statements holds. If not, I would be thankful for counterexamples.

I) For any two global, holomorphic sections $s,s'$ of $\mathcal L$, the induced divisors $\operatorname{div} s, \operatorname{div} s'$ are linear equivalent.

II) For any two global, meromorphic sections $s,s'$ of $\mathcal L$, the induced divisors $\operatorname{div} s, \operatorname{div} s'$ are linear equivalent.

III) If $D,D'$ are linear equivalent divisors on $M$ the continuous continuotation of $\overline D, \overline D'$ of $D,D'$ are linear equivalent on $\overline M$.

Thanks a lot, for your help.

Comment: For I) and II) the point is that dividing two rational sections of a line bundle is again a rational section.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani ... meaning, that for a non-trivial Linebundle the statement does not hold?

Comment: Ehsan M. Kermani probably meant to say that $s= fs^\prime$, where $f$ is a rational function. In particular, the order of $s$ along a point $P$ is the order of $f$ along $P$ plus the order of $s^\prime$ along $P$. Taking the sum over all $P$ gives you that the divisor of $s$ equals the divisor of $f$ plus the divisor of $s^\prime$. Thus, div $s$ and div $s^\prime$ differ by a principal divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, beware that  a complex manifold in general has no compactification: an open ball in $\mathbb C^n$ for example doesn't have one.
And on the other hand beware that a complex manifold may have several, non isomorphic compactifications: for example  $\mathbb C^2$ may be compactified to $\mathbb P^2$, but also to the non isomorphic $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$.

That said, II (and its special case I)  is true: if $s,s'$ are sections of a holomorphic line bundle on a complex manifold $X$, compact or not, there exists a meromorphic function $f\in \mathcal M(X)$ such that $s=fs'$ (this is easily checked locally),  so that $div (s)=div (s)'+ div(f)$ and that means by definition that $div (s)$ and $div (s')$ are linearly equivalent.

Finally the answer to III is no as shown by QiL'8, but actually the question doesn't even make sense in general!
Indeed, you mention the continuation $\bar D$ of $D$ to $\bar M$, but this  may not be a holomorphic divisor  :
for example  if $M$ is $\mathbb C^2\setminus \{0\}$ and $D$ is the graph of $\sin(1/z)$, then$\bar D$ is not analytic in $\bar M=\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$.